# How to go higher DPI by lowering 5k iMac's resolution?

Tags: display, imac, 5k

I started using 1440x810 or 1280x720 resolutions on my 5k iMac. I somewhat expected better quality because I thought it would be 2x Retina. It looks like that is not the case.

I would like to know..how come lowering resolution on my 5k does not enable HiDPI and..is there a way to do so if this is configuration issue?

Comment: *ppi* is a **physical display** related property but **not** one of the graphics projected by the window server...so even if you'd use a 1x1 resolution the ppi of your 5k iMac still is ~218.

Comment: @klanomath // In that case, I think I wasn't exactly asking PPI. When I was using lower PPI monitors before, I could make it look better by using HiDPI. How come I don't see that better quality when I go lower resolution (HiDPI) in 5k mac?

Comment: One explanation: [What is HiDPI](https://medium.com/elementaryos/what-is-hidpi-and-why-does-it-matter-b024eabea20d).  it's a misconception to think that a 1440x810 resolution projected to a 5120×2880 display is better than a 2560x1440 resolution or a 5120×2880 resolution to the same display. In fact it's the opposite: projecting a 10240×5760 resolution to a 5120×2880 display is the best in terms of crispiness. You have to blow up all GUI elements (buttons/windows/fonts) by 2 of course to make them legible/usable.

Comment: @klanomath that sounds like OS X is only optimized for certain resolutions in that case...? I actually am not following in detail..